# How can I add a string into a cell on sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, varchar

I have these tables

> **Table_1**
>   number...letters...name
>   1.....AB...Peter
>   2...BC...Paul
>   3...AC...Mary
>
> **Table_2**
>   letter...names
>   A...NULL
>   B...NULL
>   C...NULL

and I have to update Table_2 into this

> **Table_2**
>   letter...names
>   A...Peter, Mary
>   B...Peter, Paul
>   C...Paul, Mary

All are varchar except for the number row. It concatenates all names that has a specific letter on their 'letters' row. How can I do this with just one query in sql?

Comment: how the tab1 letters are map between two rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery in the `update`:

```
update table2
    set names = (select group_concat(t1.name order by number separator ', ')
                 from table1 t1
                 where t1.letters like concat('%', table2.letter, '%')
                );
```